# Using Selenium to test Website Speed

Tags: python, performance, selenium

I'm using Selenium to create something like: [tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com/)

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

logs = [json.loads(log['message'])['message'] for log in driver.get_log('performance')]

with open('devtools.json', 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(logs, f)

driver.close()
```

I'd like to ask you guys if using Selenium is the best approach to do performance test on a website.

Comment: I don't know how accurate will be the results. Selenium is not a real browser and the speed will not be the same.

Comment: If you want to check speed of page load, you can check that using selenium. But selenium is not used for other performance testing. I think you can use JMeter for this

Comment: I only need the load speed, number of requests and those kind of information

Comment: From my performace testing days, I used JMeter for load/volume testing. A simple wget with a timer in front of it would do just to measure time to load one page however. If you're aiming at testing site-wide on complex scenarios, you will need a competent tool to support that. A lengthy analysis of some of their strengths can be found here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use

Comment: I'd like to test other websites. The user puts an URL in a text field and I get the results. Load Time, Number of requests, JS Files, DOM Loaded, etc..

Comment: If you're not closely attached to Python and Selenium, you can try https://www.sitespeed.io/
"Sitespeed.io is a set of Open Source tools that makes it easy to monitor and measure the performance of your web site."